# Record visible just for selected users

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

I want to create a form where the logged author can fill a textarea and then select 1 or more system users from a checkbox

So when every user logs in he Will see that record only if he has been selected in the checkbox before.

How can i do it?
Must i save values of the checkbox in a single record and then split to set the correct data set?
And then how can i show the whole records to the current user as i want him to see a list of records where he is the author or where he is among the users allowed to set that very same record

I know this can be a generic request but the matter is i dont understand how i could do it, so the answer i look for is not "give me the code" but"explain me the main steps i must follow", someone can give me some hints?

Answer (score -1):

How about creating a table named "record" with the following structure:

```
id author_id allowed_user_id text
```

Now, when the author with id 1 selects two users with ids 2 and 3, you insert two rows into that table, one for each allowed user

```
id author_id allowed_user_id text
1  1         2               just a test
2  1         3               just a test
```

To show the current user the records he authored

```
SELECT * FROM record WHERE author_id = current_user_id
```

and records he's allowed

```
SELECT * FROM record WHERE allowed_user_id = current_user_id
```